# D3.js SVG Animations Lagging on Mobile

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, canvas, responsive-design

This is less of a code-based question and more of a best practices-based question I suppose.

I built a scrollytelling data visualization with svg elements using d3.js. While it works just fine on my desktop, it lags quite a bit on mobile (I'm thinking perhaps because mobile has less cpu/ram capability). While making it responsive using chrome dev tools for mobile, I suppose I figured because it looked fine for that particular device (which it does design-wise), it would render the elements just the same performance-wise (which it does not when deployed to an actual hard device).

I suppose my question(s) is - Is there a best practice for preventing something like this from happening? I'm assuming I should have staged this on an actual device earlier so I would pick up on something like this occurring. Moreover, (and perhaps a dump question), are there well-working svg-to-canvas converters that would allow me to override this problem (are these even a thing?), so when device width & height is detected, it would run the canvas-copy as opposed to the original svg code which is better suited for more powerful/capable devices?

Many thanks.